# How to optimize my code and the database access?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I'm creating a sme budingeting application, where I have the necessity to manage a lot of data ( huge list of products, balance sheet table etc.).

I want to have an efficient and optimized code, respecting the DRY principle and less querysets possible to the database.

Ad example this code in my views.py is it efficient and optimized?

```
def conto_economico(request):
    # Creazione tabella materie prime, sussidiarie, di consumo e merci
    defaults = list(0 for m in range(12))
    elements = dict()
    for conto_id, year, month, totale in(Materiale.objects.values_list('conto__nome', 'data__year', 'data__month').annotate(totale=ExpressionWrapper(Sum(F('quantita') * F('prezzo')),
        output_field=FloatField())).values_list('conto__nome', 'data__year', 'data__month', 'totale').order_by("conto_id")) :
        if conto_id not in elements.keys():
            elements[conto_id]=list(defaults)
        index=month-1
        elements[conto_id][index]=totale

    total_elements={'Per materie prime, sussidiarie, di consumo e di merci': [sum(t) for t in zip(*elements.values())],}
```

I utilize this code for a lot of model to create my tables, but I think that are not efficient.

This is my model:

```
class MaterialeManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            iva_amount=ExpressionWrapper(F('quantita')*F('prezzo')*F('iva'),output_field=FloatField())
        ).annotate(totale_netto=ExpressionWrapper(F('quantita')*F('prezzo'),output_field=FloatField()))


class Materiale(models.Model):
    conto = models.ForeignKey(Conto, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    tipologia = models.ForeignKey(Tipologia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    sottocategoria = models.ForeignKey(Sottocategoria, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    um = models.CharField('U.M.', max_length=30, unique=False, blank=True, default="")
    quantita=models.DecimalField('Quantità',max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default="")
    prezzo=models.DecimalField('Prezzo di acquisto', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default="")
    iva=models.DecimalField('I.V.A. in %', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default="0.22")
    data=models.DateField('Data di acquisto', default="GG/MM/YYYY")
    giorni_dilazione=models.IntegerField('Giorni dilazione pagamento', default="")
    objects=MaterialeManager()
```

I want to obtain, based on the data of registration, a monthly tables that sum all "`quantita`" amount for each single "`conto`".

Comment: it is really hard to visualize what you want to achieve with this code. Maybe you can share the models and a visual representation of the outcome you get from this code.

Comment: I have added the model and what I want to do with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a Django orm expert, but I'll try to give my answare

```py
contos = Conto.objects.prefetch_related('materiale_set').annotate(totale=Sum('materiale__quantita'))
```

Now, if you want just tha january/2020 Contos, just

```py
january_contos = contos.filter(materiale__date__year=2020, materiale__date__month=1)
```

I think that this way you don't iterate over every `Materiale` record, but just over the number of months that you need, letting the sql query make sums instead of python code. Prefetch is important here, or you will do a huge number of subqueries.